# Several second computation in a game while maintaining 60 FPS

Tags: actionscript-3, game-engine

I've got an algorithm that takes more than several seconds to complete. I'm trying to implement it into a 60fps flash game i'm creating. I am wondering if there is some provision in ActionScript3 to interrupt a computation in order to update the frame and continue the computation afterwards. There probably isn't, so I'm assuming the best method would be to perform the computation for x milliseconds, measure what the frame rate is after, then adjust the time the computation will run for next frame if the frame rate is less than or greater than 60 fps. The drawback with this is that the game won't run at a steady 60fps...

Any other ideas on how to (optimally) perform a large computation in AS3 while maintaining the framerate?

EDIT: For the curious (the calculation, perhaps I should have said algorithm):
I'm creating a motion planning library for game AI objects (one use for motion planning). The algorithm is along the lines of a RRT (rapidly exploring random tree) that iterates thousands of times.

Demo link: http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1279044355

Click to motion plan. The circle can "thrust" at a fixed magnitude in any direction.

Also - there is no linear velocity damping (i.e. friction).

Comment: 60fps seems really high for a Flash game. I usually keep it at 30 for a game but anything else I crank it to 60.

Comment: I can't imagine what the heck would be taking so long to compute!  This doesn't answer your question, but this may be a sign of missing an opportunity to cache the computation (either at level load time or before the game starts) or highlight a need to restructure your data (focus on real time lighting versus recomputing lightmaps at runtime).

Out of curiosity, would you mind explaining what it is that you are trying to compute that takes so long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you do the "calculation" in stages, and then just do one stage per frame until it's done?  Split it up into chunks that you know can fit into a frame, and do it over time.

A couple of examples:

One game I worked on computed line of sight between entities.  It took a long time and the hardware wasn't very powerful, so we only updated the line of sight for one object each frame.  The player's line of sight was updated every other frame, and the enemies were updated round-robin in the intervening frames.

If instead you're calculating something based on a large dataset, partition that data into smaller chunks and do only one chunk per frame.  For instance, if you need to figure out the closest star to your ship, and there are a million stars, maybe only do a thousand per frame.

Maybe your calculation is not easily mappable to either of these; if you have an example of what you're trying to accomplish it would be very helpful!

Comment: It can be broken into chunks, but what I was trying to figure out was how to calculate how large each chunk should be. 

If the chunk is too big it will delay the display update - causing an FPS drop. If the chunk is too small then the calculation will take longer to finish and I'll have wasted cycles.

Comment: I agree with dash-tom-bang. Senocular wrote a good tutorial on exactly this issue. http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/asyncoperations/

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for Allan!

Comment: Though, after actually reading the article it doesn't answer the question of finding an optimal way to break the computation into chunks. I guess I'll stick to the method I suggested.

Comment: Yeah. One other suggestion, depending on the nature of calculation, could you offload some/all of it to PixelBender as it runs in a separate thread. I realise that it could only work with some types of calculations but worth a shot :)

Comment: It's actually a loop that explores the stage for a path around obstacles (but it's not a graph search because the search space is continuous) so that won't be possible. I'll see how implementing the idea I suggested in the original post goes. Seems like setting a conservative estimate on computation time then adjusting that based on the frame rate is a fail-safe idea. Perhaps I'll see 5 - 10 fps drops every so often but that's not horrible.

Comment: You can run a few "small" jobs up front to see how long they take, and then scale your chunk size by the time you have available for the computation.  E.g. if one chunk takes 1ms to run and you have 5ms available at the end of a frame, queue up five chunks.  This would depend on a constant chunk size, but generally you'll need a way to determine how long a body of work will take before you run it.  This would be "easy" if you had a proper threading library available, since you could just run it at low priority and yield regularly, sleeping the main thread for the time remaining in the frame.

Comment: Is there any way to determine how much time you have left for computation in AS3? I have several EnterFrame event functions for each object (GameActor, EnemyObject, Bullet... and one for the overall Engine) that I don't know the order of execution. What I could do to remedy this is use the overall Engine EnterFrame handler to fire events for each of the game objects. Hmm... i'll see how this goes.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the type of your calculation you could write a Pixel Bender Kernel that does the processing in the background using a ShaderJob:

http://www.boostworthy.com/blog/?p=243

http://www.huesforalice.com/project/47

Alternatively here is another link to a tutorial how to implement pseudo threading in Actionscript: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2008/01/threads_in_actionscript_3.html

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
flash player has been supporting  [workers](http://help.adobe.com/fr_FR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) since 11.4

background workers allow to perform tasks in the background without blocking the main worker which seems perfectly suited to your needs. As a nice bonus, on multicore cpu, background workers will be able to run in parallel without slowing down the main worker

AIR mobile doesn't support workers on iOs for the moment though (AIR 4.0 & AIR 13 beta)..

Also, as already said by others, path finding should not be so long ! you should consider using another algorithm, because *Rapid* does not sound compatible with *an algorithm that takes more than several seconds to complete*. Most famous path finding algorithm is [A star (A*)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm)